# Convert C++ double to DEC double

Tags: c++

I want to be able to take a user given double and write out in the DEC 64 dpfp format (http://www.wsmr.army.mil/RCCsite/Documents/106%20Previous%20Versions/106-07/appendixO.pdf). Having trouble getting this to line up correctly, anyone have experience or have written conversion functions for DEC types?

Comment: Refresh my memory, was DEC big-endian or little-endian?

Comment: Little-endian I believe

Comment: 2 minutes after I created my own answer I found this: http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2005/1424/of2005-1424_v1.2.pdf

Comment: If you'd like to share what worked for you, you can post an answer of your own - answers shouldn't be edited into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty straight forward, let me take a shot at it. Note that I don't have any way of testing this for correctness.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> ToDEC64Float(double d)
{
    uint64_t dec_bits = 0ULL;
    if (d != 0.0)
    {
        assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t));
        uint64_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&d);
        uint64_t fraction = bits & 0x000fffffffffffffULL;
        int exp = (int)((bits >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1023;
        bool sign = (bool)(bits & 0x8000000000000000ULL);
        // convert the individual values for the new format
        fraction <<= 3;
        exp += 1 + 128;
        if (exp > 255)
            throw std::overflow_error("overflow");
        if (exp < 0 || (exp == 0 && fraction != 0))
            throw std::underflow_error("underflow");
        dec_bits = (uint64_t)sign << 63 | (uint64_t)exp << 55 | fraction;
    }
    std::vector<unsigned char> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i+=8)
        result.push_back((unsigned char)((dec_bits >> i) & 0xff));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tried out your method with some test data

Comment: Output using code posted above when taking a DEC value, converting to double and converting back again. I realize there is some loss that occurs and it is not one for one, but figured it should at least be somewhat close

Comment: @favre45 the problem with that approach is that the error might be in either the conversion *to* or the conversion *from*. Worse would be if you had errors in both that compensated for each other, leading you to believe it's correct when it's not. The only true test is to compare the result to a known number in the correct format.

Comment: The input uint64_t value (9707381994276473045) for DECBytesToDouble is a true DEC type, and the output confirms the known real value (109527.7465).

Answer (score 0):

```
double static const DECBytesToDouble(uint64_t value)
{
  //DEC Byte Conversion Constants
  static const float MANTISSA_CONSTANT = 0.5;
  static const int32_t EXPONENT_BIAS = 128;
  uint8_t * byte_array = (uint8_t*)&value;
  uint8_t first = byte_array[0];
  uint8_t second = byte_array[1];
  uint8_t third = byte_array[2];
  uint8_t fourth = byte_array[3];
  uint8_t fifth = byte_array[4];
  uint8_t sixth = byte_array[5];
  uint8_t seventh = byte_array[6];
  uint8_t eighth = byte_array[7];
  // |second  |first|fourth|third|sixth|fifth|eighth|seventh|
  // |s|exponent|mantissa                                   |
  bool sign = second & 0x80;
  std::cout<<"(DECBytesToDouble) Sign: "<<sign<<std::endl;
  int32_t exponent = ((second & 0x7F) << 1) + ((first >> 7) & 0x1);
  std::cout<<"(DECBytesToDouble) Exponent: "<<exponent<<std::endl;
  int64_t mantissa = ((int64_t)(first & 0x7F) << 48) + ((int64_t)fourth << 40) 
     + ((int64_t)third << 32) + ((int64_t)sixth << 24) + ((int64_t)fifth << 16) 
     + ((int64_t)eighth << 8) + (int64_t)     seventh;
  std::cout<<"(DECBytesToDouble) Fraction: "<<mantissa<<std::endl;
  double fraction = MANTISSA_CONSTANT;
  for (int32_t i=0; i<55; i++)
  {
     fraction += ((mantissa >> i) & 0x1) * pow(2,i-56);
  }//for
  return pow(-1,sign)*fraction*pow(2,exponent-EXPONENT_BIAS);
}//DECBytesToDouble


uint64_t static const DoubleToDECBytes(double value)
{
  static const int32_t EXPONENT_BIAS = 128;
  uint64_t dec_bits = 0ULL;
  if (value != 0.0)
  {
     uint64_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&value);
     uint64_t fraction = bits & 0x000fffffffffffffULL;
     int exp = (int)((bits >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1023;
     bool sign = false;
     if(value < 0)
     {
        sign = true;
     }//if
     std::cout<<"(DoubleToDECBytes) Sign: "<<sign<<std::endl;
     // convert the individual values for the new format
     fraction <<= 3;
     exp += EXPONENT_BIAS + 1;
     std::cout<<"(DoubleToDECBytes) Exponent: "<<exp<<std::endl;
     std::cout<<"(DoubleToDECBytes) Fraction: "<<fraction<<std::endl;
     if (exp > 255)
        throw std::overflow_error("overflow");
     if (exp < 0 || (exp == 0 && fraction != 0))
        throw std::underflow_error("underflow");
     dec_bits = (uint64_t)(sign << 63) | (uint64_t)(exp << 55) | fraction;
     //|second  |first|fourth|third|sixth|fifth|eighth|seventh|
     uint8_t * byte_array = (uint8_t*)&dec_bits;
     uint8_t first = byte_array[0];
     uint8_t second = byte_array[1];
     uint8_t third = byte_array[2];
     uint8_t fourth = byte_array[3];
     uint8_t fifth = byte_array[4];
     uint8_t sixth = byte_array[5];
     uint8_t seventh = byte_array[6];
     uint8_t eighth = byte_array[7];
     byte_array[7] = second;
     byte_array[6] = first;
     byte_array[5] = fourth;
     byte_array[4] = third;
     byte_array[3] = sixth;
     byte_array[2] = fifth;
     byte_array[1] = eighth;
     byte_array[0] = seventh;
     std::cout<<"(DoubleToDECBytes) Guess ="<<dec_bits<<std::endl;

  }//if
  /*std::vector<unsigned char> result;
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; i+=8)
  {
     result.push_back((unsigned char)((dec_bits >> i) & 0xff));
  }//for
  uint64_t final_result = 0;
  memcpy(&final_result, &result[0], sizeof(uint64_t));
  std::cout<<"Final result: "<<final_result<<std::endl;*/
  return dec_bits;
}//DoubleToDECBytes

Output:
input uint64_t value: 9707381994276473045
(DECBytesToDouble) Sign: 0
(DECBytesToDouble) Exponent: 145
(DECBytesToDouble) Fraction: 24184718387676855
output double value: 109527.7465
(DoubleToDECBytes) Sign: 0
(DoubleToDECBytes) Exponent: 145
(DoubleToDECBytes) Fraction: 24184718387676848
(DoubleToDECBytes) Guess =9705411669439479893
Converted double, uint64_t: 9705411669439479893
uint64_t difference: 1970324836993152
(DECBytesToDouble) Sign: 0
(DECBytesToDouble) Exponent: 0
(DECBytesToDouble) Fraction: 24184718387676848
output double value: 0.0000
```

Comment: @MarkRansom Above is where I currently am at, can't quite get to convert back and forth

Answer (score 0):

I came to find that integrating libvaxdata C library into my C++ solution was the best way to go. In my use case situation all that was required was some byte flipping, however the routines work flawlessly.

I recommend the libvaxdata library when dealing with conversion to/from IEEE/DEC types.

http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2005/1424/